# Get current position does not work on iPhone

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the script below that shows my current position. It works fine on desktop pc but I don't understand why doesn't work on iPhone. What's wrong?

```
<script>

function success(position) {
  var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
  mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
  mapcanvas.style.height = '400px';
  mapcanvas.style.width = '100%';

  document.querySelector('#map').appendChild(mapcanvas);

  var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

  var options = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: coords,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coords,
      map: map,
      title:"You are here!"
  });
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
  error('Geo Location is not supported');
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of HTML5, when you request methods like this, the browser must request user permissions at the first time you try to get current position.

[image]

Check this: [Using Geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation)

Comment: Yes, I know it but doesn't happen anything on iPhone. The browser doesn't require the permission to use the geolocation. For example if I visit this page http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/google_maps_geo_location/  on my iphone i can't get my current position but instead works fine on my desktop pc

Comment: What is the iOS version? The browser you have support HTML5?

Comment: I solved! For some reason my "location services"  on my iphone was disabled.